# Serving react app with NGINX on /admin instead of / loads files but does not render application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, docker, kubernetes

I'm having a bit of an issue serving my react application through the NGINX docker container on Kubernetes.

The end point is alive, I can see it load it's resources...but that is it. It does not render anything. Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.1.0-alpine AS builder

RUN mkdir /home/app

WORKDIR /home/app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

# ---- Base Release Image
FROM nginx:1.13.1-alpine

COPY ./config/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /home/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Here are the default.conf I use for NGINX:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location /admin {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

If serve this in any other path besides /, it doesn't render. As soon as I serve it on any relative path it craps out even though it loads the content.

I have no idea what else to try.